# How to pass color to custom xml item in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-custom-view

I have a custom shape for `button's dashed border`. With `hardcoded color` everything works as expected, but I need to `pass color from outside`. How can I do it?

Here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid/>
        <corners android:radius="16dip" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/blue"
            android:dashWidth="3dp"
            android:dashGap="3dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

and this is usage

```
android:background="@drawable/dashed_border_button"
```

[image]

I need to change border color from hardcoded to dynamic

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?  Can you clarify that, are you wanting to use a different skin on button press?

Comment: I want to use different colors on different screens let's say.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the same by using another Drawable resource file wit the attribute Stroke - Color = "your color"
and then setting the background Drawable to new Drawable file

```
 yourview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.another);
```

This is because the method :

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(as.getBackground(),Color.BLUE);
```

Set even the solid fill color to the blue (here in this case) , which you don't want.
Hope it helps!!`

Comment: Could you please share the code from another drawable?

Comment: When I am trying to create stroke with only color - I loose all other parameters (width, shape, gap)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get background() from your view and make

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(color, DrawableCompat.wrap(view.bacground())
```

Comment: This colors full background of the button. I only need to change color of stroke